# auto variable initialized to Zero

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    x=x>0?x:x+1;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

In this x is initialized to 0, but why? Wrote and compiled the code in GCC

Comment: value of uninitialized variable depends on compiler. It can be either 0 of a junk value based on heap handling of the compiler

Answer (score 1):

Use of uninitialized variable is cause for undefined behavior. One compiler may initialize the variable to `0`, but that could easily change if you change compilers or even by changes to compile flags, such as using different optimization levels.

Don't count on it.

Answer (score 1):

It is an undefined behavior. You are not initializing the value for x. If you are
not doing that , then it take some garbage value. Garbage value can any value we can't expect that this value will come. So simply initialize the variable you are using.